# Font Awesome in Avada theme not showing in Chrome, Firefox but showing on Internet Explorer

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I have installed avada theme on my website www.picapotion.com
Everything is working good but Font-awesome icons are not showing on any browser except Internet Explorer.
Kindly help me in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Create or edit the .htaccess file in the root folder on the same domain where the fonts are hosted, and add the following code into it:

```
# Apache config
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I added your code in .htaccess file and refresh the page, the next moment I am facing the Internal Server Error 500

Comment: Now I am facing another issue :( I can't access my website. Please let me know how to get icons visible to all browsers.